# Display featured image metadata?

Tags: post-thumbnails

Display featured image file size, extension, filename, type, orientation?
How to display some information of featured image in post.

I need to display like this in post:

Detail Of Easter Desktop Wallpaper Widescreen
Posted : February 13, 2017 At 9:46 Am

Author : Admin

Category : Easter

Tags : Beautiful, Cool, Desktop

Viewed : 1334 Visitor

File Size : 324 KB

File Type : Image/Jpeg

Resolution : 2560x1920 Pixel

Download : Smartphone ° Tablet ° Desktop (Original)

Download Many Resolution: Click Here (To Attachment Page)

pls, i am newbie, make it easy for me to understand. thnks

Comment: This is quite open ended, you will need to break this apart into smaller multiple questions, else it's quite broad. E.g. 10 questions each for the 10 steps in baking a cake, vs what we have here "how to cake?"

Comment: I can understand your problem except this "Download : Smartphone ° Tablet ° Desktop (Original)" . can you please explain me what is this . so can give you full code in answer.

Answer (score 1):

The featured image is just an attachment, and you can retrieve its post ID via `get_post_thumbnail_id`, e.g.

```
$featured_image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post );
```

At which point you're dealing with a standard post of type `attachment`. Other than checking that there is a featured image, no special handling is needed and it can be treated as any other attachment post.

In fact, internally setting the featured image is just putting a post ID in a particular post meta field.

```
function get_post_thumbnail_id( $post = null ) {
    $post = get_post( $post );
    if ( ! $post ) {
        return '';
    }
    return get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_thumbnail_id', true );
}
```

Though I would recommend using the function instead of going straight for the post meta.

As for how to get the size, type, format of an `attachment` post, that's another question that you should open a new question for ( or refer to the main good answers that already exist )

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code as you wanted *except this "Download : Smartphone ° Tablet ° Desktop (Original)"*. you can see in this screenshot http://prntscr.com/mmidnl

> ***1. you can below code in functions.php file for visitors count.***
>   ***Reference:*** https://www.themexpert.com/blog/track-display-post-views-in-wordpress

**function to display number of posts.**

```
function getPostViews($postID){
    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
        return "0 Visitor";
    }
    return $count.' Visitors';
}
```

**function to count views.**

```
function setPostViews($postID) {
    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        $count = 0;
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
    }else{
        $count++;
        update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);
    }
}
```

**Remove issues with prefetching adding extra views**

```
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'adjacent_posts_rel_link_wp_head', 10, 0);
```

> **2. Put this below code in single.php file.**

***This part of the tracking views code will set the post views. Just place this code below within the single.php file inside the WordPress Loop.***

```
<div class="data">
<div>Detail Of <?php the_title(); ?> Posted : <?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?> At <?php the_time('g:i a'); ?></div>
<div>Author : <?php the_author(); ?></div>
<div>Category : <?php the_category( ', ' ); ?></div>
<div><?php the_tags( 'Tags: '); ?> </div>
<div><?php setPostViews(get_the_ID()); ?>Viewed : <?php echo getPostViews(get_the_ID()); ?></div>
<div><?php $image_data = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), "full" ); $img_s = get_headers($image_data[0], 1); $img_size_wd =  $img_s["Content-Length"]/1024; $img_size_kb = number_format((float)$img_size_wd, 2, '.', ''); ?>File Size : <?php echo $img_size_kb; ?> KB</div>
<div><?php $img_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID); $type =  get_post_mime_type( $img_id ); ?>File Type : <?php echo $type; ?></div>
<div><?php $image_data = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), "full" ); ?> Resolution : <?php echo $image_data[1]; ?> x <?php echo $image_data[2]; ?> Pixel</div>
<div><?php $img_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID); ?>Download Many Resolution: <?php echo '<a href="'. get_attachment_link($img_id) . '">Click Here</a>'; ?></div>
</div>
```